# Raymarching tangents

Tags: shaders, glsl, fragment-shader

I've recently started to experiment with raymarching over on shadertoy.com. It seems common to find the normal for a distance field like so:

```
vec3 scene_normal(vec3 p)
{
    vec3 e = vec3(0.001, 0.0, 0.0);

    vec3 n = vec3(
        scene_distance(p + e.xyy) - scene_distance(p - e.xyy),
        scene_distance(p + e.yxy) - scene_distance(p - e.yxy),
        scene_distance(p + e.yyx) - scene_distance(p - e.yyx));

    return normalize(n);
}
```

However, I can't seem to find anything about tangents. Is there a similar method to find tangents generically for a scene, or do I have to generate them specifically for the shapes I'm raymarching?

Comment: This isn't a great answer so leaving it as a comment, but one way would be to cross product your normal against some other vector (maybe an up vector) to get one tangent, then cross product against that result to get the other tangent (bi-tangent). This is not so great though because if your normal is the same as the first vector you use for cross product, you have problems. Also, I don't think the results are consistent across a shape.  It does technically "work" though.

Comment: @AlanWolfe Normally the other vector you use are texture coordinates, maybe OP has them available, and could use them for the basis?

Comment: In Ray marching you don't have access to the texture coordinates unfortunately. Neat trick for when using rasterization though. I'll remember that